# SQL: how to get value based upon value earlier in query

Tags: sql

See code below. The itemdescription I want to get back depends on the value from itemcode. The value returned by max(itemcode) should be matched to the right itemdescription.

New to SQL and willing to learn :)

```
select ordernumber
, max(quantity)
, max(itemcode)
, max(itemdescription)
from salesorderlines
group by ordernumber;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Column deliverydate  data type?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Using the invantive  program and delivery date data type is datetime

Comment: And you don't even mention what quantity is doing in the query.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the rows from `salesorderlines` that have the maximum quantity for each `orderdid` (that is my best guess of a reasonable question that your query would attempt to answer).

If so, think "filtering", not "aggregation":

```
select sol.*
from salesorderlines sol
where sol.quantity = (select max(sol2.quantity)
                      from salesorderlines sol2
                      where sol2.quantity = sol.quantity
                     );
```

Comment: Yes, i do need the salesorderlines that have the maximum quantity for each orderid. However, ive tried that and it gives back that sol.quantity is an unknown identifier.

Comment: @jopbrouwer . . . `quantity` is defined in your question.  And `sol` is defined in the outer query.   This should work in any database.